# Filtering of a parameter pack of the variadic template function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

I want to "filter" a parameter pack of the variadic template function like in the following code (need to "filter" only variables of certain types):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Z {};

struct test
{

    using result_type = void;

    template< typename... P >
    result_type apply_filter(P &&... _p) const
    {
        using std::forward;
        return operator () (forward< P >(_p)...);
    }

    template< typename... T >
    result_type operator () (std::string const & _s, T &&... _tail) const
    {
        std::cout << _s << std::endl;
        return operator () (std::forward< T >(_tail)...);
    }

    template< typename... T >
    result_type operator () (double const & _x, T &&... _tail) const
    {
        std::cout << _x << std::endl;
        return operator () (std::forward< T >(_tail)...);
    }

    template< typename... T >
    result_type operator () (Z const &, T &&... _tail) const
    {
        std::cout << "z" << std::endl;
        return operator () (std::forward< T >(_tail)...);
    }

private :

    result_type operator () () const { return; }

    template< typename T, typename U >
    using is_the_same = std::is_same< typename std::remove_const< typename std::remove_reference< T >::type >::type, U >;

    template< typename T >
    typename std::enable_if< is_the_same< T, std::string >::value, std::string >::type
    forward(T && _s) const
    {
        return "\"" + _s + "\"";
    }

    template< typename T >
    typename std::enable_if< is_the_same< T, double >::value, double >::type
    forward(T && _x) const
    {
        return _x + 1.0;
    }

};

int main()
{
    test test_;
    double x = 0.0;
    std::string s = "s";
    Z z;
    test_.apply_filter(x, s, z);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But `std::forward` has a higher priority than member function in `apply_filter`. Thus there is no filtering occurs here.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: 1) Why do you change the designated output in `forward` and not in `operator()`? 2) You could define another "layer" of functions which are all defined in your class and call them instead of `forward` in `apply_filter`.

Comment: What's wrong with changing every `std::cout << ... << std::endl;` to `std::cout << forward(...) << std::endl;`?

Comment: @jrok Expected output is `1 "s" z`

Comment: @DyP I write all in single `class` for simplicity sake. `apply_filter` should have one additional template parameter (named `forward`) for passing a functor-"filter". `operator`s should grupped into another `class` to form the visitor (in boost library sense).

Comment: @TomKnapen This is not my intention.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Z { };

struct test
{

    using result_type = void;

    template< typename... P >
    result_type apply_filter(P &&... _p) const
    {
        return operator () (forward<P>(_p)...);
    }

    template< typename... T >
    result_type operator () (std::string const & _s, T &&... _tail) const
    {
        std::cout << _s << std::endl;
        return operator () (std::forward< T >(_tail)...);
    }

    template< typename... T >
    result_type operator () (double const & _x, T &&... _tail) const
    {
        std::cout << _x << std::endl;
        return operator () (std::forward< T >(_tail)...);
    }

    template< typename... T >
    result_type operator () (Z const &, T &&... _tail) const
    {
        std::cout << "z" << std::endl;
        return operator () (std::forward< T >(_tail)...);
    }

private:

    result_type operator () () const { }

    template< typename T, typename U >
    using is_the_same = std::is_same<typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type, U>;

    template<typename T>
    using is_known_type = typename std::conditional<(is_the_same<T, std::string>::value || is_the_same<T, double>::value), std::true_type, std::false_type>::type;

    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<is_the_same<T, std::string>::value, std::string>::type
    forward_impl(T && _s, std::true_type) const
    {
        return "\"" + _s + "\"";
    }

    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<is_the_same<T, double>::value, double>::type
    forward_impl(T && _x, std::true_type) const
    {
        return _x + 1.0;
    }

#define RETURNS(exp) -> decltype(exp) { return exp; }

    template<typename T>
    auto forward_impl(T && t, std::false_type) const
    RETURNS(std::forward<T>(t))

    template<typename T>
    auto forward(T && t) const
    RETURNS(forward_impl(std::forward<T>(t), is_known_type<T>()))

#undef RETURNS
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    test test_;
    double x = 0.0;
    std::string s = "s";
    Z z;
    test_.apply_filter(x, s, z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that I can simply repeat the definition (as member function) for `std::forward` (for `T &&` and `T &` versions) for "other" types. But I prefer to use the `std::forward` directly instead. But, it seems to me, that's impossible.

Comment: If you _want_ to use `std::forward`, you need to call your own `forward` inside of your `operator()`'s (as I suggested in my comment to your question). If you don't _need_ to use `std::forward`, my answer shows you one way to do it.

Comment: I want to use `std::forward` particularly for "other" types and my filter functions defined for some case of specific types. This is because the `std::forward` already exists and ugly to write twice the same functionality.